# Python filter row with multiple columns conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, filter

I have a CSV dataset and I need to filter it with conditions but the problem is that the condition can be true for multiple days. What I  want is to keep the last true value for this condition.

My dataset looks like this

```
Date           City        Summary       FlightNo.   Terminal     Company
2-18-2019       NY        Airplane Land      23          7         Delta 
2-18-2019     London     Cargo handling      4           5         British
2-18-2019      Dubai     Airplane land       92          7         Emirates
2-19-2019      Dubai     Airplane stay       92          5         Emirates
2-19-2019      Paris     Flight cancel       78          2         British
2-19-2019     London     Airplane Land       4           5         British
2-19-2019       LA       Airplane Land       7           2         United
2-20-2019      Dubai     Airplane land       92          3         Emirates
2-20-2019       LA       Airplane land       29          3         Delta
2-20-2019       NY       Airplane left       23          1         Delta
2-21-2019      Paris     Airplane reschedu   78          2         British
2-21-2019      London    Airplane land       4           3         British
2-21-2019       LA    Airplane from NY land  29          5         Delta
~~~
3-10-2019      London    Airplane land       5           5         KLM
3-10-2019      Paris     Airplane Land       78          7         AirFrance
3-10-2019       LA       Reschedule          29          4         United
3-11-2019       NY       Cargo handled       23          7         Delta
3-11-2019      Dubai     Arrived be4 2 day   34          7         Etihad
~~~
3-21-2019      Dubai      Airplane land      92          5         Emirates
3-21-2019     New Delhi   Reschedule         9           4         AirAsia
3-21-2019      London     Cargo handling     5           2         Lufthansa
3-22-2019     New Delhi   Airplane Land      9           3         AirAsia
3-22-2019       NY        Reschedule         23          2         United
3-22-2019      Dubai      Airplane land      35          1         Emirates
```

So the code should give us the last entry for plane landing where `City == City` and `Flight No. == Flight No` and `Company == Company`. As you can see this condition can be true for multiple days. So If all the three conditions are true and Summary contains `Airplane Lands` return the last true entire

Edited
The desired output should look like the dataset below:

```
Date           City        Summary       FlightNo.   Terminal     Company
2-18-2019       NY       Airplane Land       23          7         Delta 
2-19-2019       LA       Airplane Land       7           2         United
2-20-2019      Dubai     Airplane land       92          3         Emirates
2-21-2019      London    Airplane Land       4           3         British
2-21-2019       LA    Airplane from NY land  29          5         Delta
~~~
3-10-2019      London    Airplane land       5           5         KLM
3-10-2019      Paris     Airplane Land       78          7         AirFrance
~~~
3-21-2019      Dubai      Airplane land      92          5         Emirates
3-22-2019     New Delhi   Airplane Land      9           3         AirAsia
3-22-2019      Dubai      Airplane land      35          1         Emirates
```

As shown above to delete row all three columns(City, FlightNo., and Company) should be the same if any of them is different then both rows should be kept.

The logic of it:
Condition1: If df[Summary] contains "Airplane" and "land" return the row
Condition2: Frome the already filtered dataset If df[City] == df[City] and df[FlightNo.] == df[FlightNo.] and df[Company] == df[Company] is true with  3 days then keep either the last or the first.
So if returns rows with airplane land in the same city with same flight number runned by the same company on the 18th and 20th then one day row should be kept only. But if it was on the 1st and 15th from the same month then keep both rows.

Please help me find a what to apply all condition and keep the last **True** entrie.

EDIT:

Keep first if condition are true in the next 3 days
Input

```
print (df)
     Date      City Code      Summary      Flight No.   Company
0   2-18-2019    021        Airplane land      23       Emirates
1   2-18-2019    013        Airplane land      23       Etihad
2   2-19-2019    021        Airplane land      23       Emirates
3   2-19-2019    013        Airplane Land      23       Etihad
4   2-20-2019    021        Airplane land      23       Emirates
5   2-20-2019    055        Airplane land      23       Emirates
6   2-20-2019    013        Airplane land      23       Etihad
7   2-21-2019    021        Airplane land      23       Emirates
8   2-21-2019    013        Airplane land      78       Emirates
9   2-21-2019    055  Airplane from NY land    23       Emirates
10  2-22-2019    021        Airplane land      78       Emirates
11  2-22-2019    013        Airplane Land      78       Emirates
12  2-22-2019    055        Airplane land      78       Emirates
13  2-23-2019    021        Airplane land      78       Etihad
```

Output:

```
print (df)
         Date      City Code      Summary      Flight No.   Company
    0   2-18-2019    021        Airplane land      23       Emirates
    1   2-18-2019    013        Airplane land      23       Etihad
    5   2-20-2019    055        Airplane land      23       Emirates
    7   2-21-2019    021        Airplane land      23       Emirates
    8   2-21-2019    013        Airplane land      78       Emirates
    10  2-22-2019    021        Airplane land      78       Emirates
    12  2-22-2019    055        Airplane land      78       Emirates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
#convert to datetimes
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

#sortig by datetimes
df = df.sort_values(['City Code', 'Flight No.','Company','Date'])

#filter case non sensitive
df=df[(df.Summary.str.contains('Airplane ') & df.Summary.str.contains('Land', case=False))]

s = df.groupby(['City Code', 'Flight No.','Company'])['Date'].transform('first')
#get diff by first date per groups
df['diff'] = df['Date'].sub(s).dt.days.fillna(0)
#group column each 3 days
df['g'] = (df['diff'] // 3 )
#filter 3 days window from first per groups
df = df[~df.duplicated(['City Code', 'Flight No.','Company','g'])]
print (df)
         Date City Code        Summary  Flight No.   Company
0  2019-02-18       021  Airplane land          23  Emirates
1  2019-02-18       013  Airplane land          23    Etihad
5  2019-02-20       055  Airplane land          23  Emirates
7  2019-02-21       021  Airplane land          23  Emirates
8  2019-02-21       013  Airplane land          78  Emirates
10 2019-02-22       021  Airplane land          78  Emirates
12 2019-02-22       055  Airplane land          78  Emirates
13 2019-02-23       021  Airplane land          78    Etihad
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but I tried it and it filtered half of the dataset which what I do not want. **If City == City and No. == No. and summary contains Airplane & Land then keep the last within two days.** So if the condition is true on the 9th ,10th, 11th and 25th then it should return the rows in the 11th and 25th. So I only need to filter the repeated within 3 days if it is more than that then keep the row

Comment: @SMO - can you test now?

Comment: It actually deleted more than the previous one. because it returns one row per day. More than on city can exit in the same day and even the same city can appear the next day if it has different No.

Comment: @SMO - Can yiu change data sample for see how this not working?

Comment: I have change the data sample

Comment: @SMO - answer was edited, can you check?

Comment: It worked in removing all duplicates. I want to remove duplicates within 3 days. So If the row appears on the 1st and 3ed of january Keep the one on the 3ed but if it appears on the 1st and 10th of january we should keep both

Comment: I updated it now would you please check. I really appreciate it.

Comment: '''df = np.where((df['City'] == df['City']) & (df['Company'] == df['Company']) & (df['Flight No.'] == df['Flight No.']) where date-date <= 3 days''' this is the logic. I'm not able to find the right code

Comment: @SMO - Can you test edited answer?

Comment: I tried but it either delete rows that should be kept or keep duplicated row and it is so ransom that the same condition is applied for one row but not the other. However the original data has many other columns but is not related to the condition that why I didn't include them to simplify the example

Comment: @SMO - so problem is still not good sample data?

Comment: Please have another look I changed some enteries

Comment: **df = np.where((df['City'] == df['City']) & (df['Company'] == df['Company']) & (df['Flight No.'] == df['Flight No.']) And Date -Date < 3 days keep last** I just want to have the right syntax for this line. I would really appreciate your help. P.s: it is ok also to keep the first since the important is not having redundancy

Comment: @SMO - OK, today I try add some solution.

Comment: @SMO - In my opinion still problem in sample data. So created some sample with 2 groups and different datetimes. Is possible create expected ouput from this data? Be free change datetimes for better explain what means `Date -Date < 3 days keep last`. Thanks.

Comment: @SMO - because solution above filter by last tow per groups, in changed data row=6, row13, extract datetimes for these rows - `2-10-2019`, `3-11-2019` and filter - 3days so it means `2-10-2019 - 3days = 30-9-2019` and `3-11-2019 - 3days = 1-11-2019`. But if not working in real data maybe need something else.

Comment: I have included an image of my real data if you kindly can have a look since nothing worked so far

Comment: @SMO - I think our problem is explanation what need. I create sample data for possible expalin it, in 2 groups of data. Your pictures unfortunately not help. because first is necessary working with sample data and then apply solution to real data.

Comment: @SMO - here is same problem - your sample data are not good. because copied from real data. Is necessary check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and I am 100% sure your last EDIT are not sample data possible use for verifyable data which help explain your problem.

Comment: @SMO - unfortuantely last EDIT are worse like before, because picture, so cannot copied, unnecessary columns, not clear what are groups :(

Comment: I understand I is complicated I include one week with deleting most of the column. However including is it  important since most solution assume the whole row is duplicated with is not although my original sample is duplicated you can see now it the easiest way to give an example of the real data

Comment: @SMO - yes, it is hard. But without explanation I cannot help you, because not understand it. And mainly without good sample data whcih is problem here. Be free change my sample data, but need only few groups, 2-3 with e.g. 3-4 rows in each. then is easy verify if working solution - from my side and same from your and last is possible apply solution to real data.

Comment: I have updated your sample hopefully it is clear

Comment: @SMO - thanks, I just test it. I have question. For group `021, 23, Emirates` areprocessing dates `2-18-2019,2-19-2019,2-20-2019, 2-21-2019` and in output are `2-18-2019,2-21-2019`, now I am confused, it is less like 3 days? thank you for patience.

Comment: @SMO For group `013, 23, Etihad` are processing dates `2-18-2019,2-19-2019,2-20-2019` and in output are `2-18-2019`, why?

Comment: Hi @jezrael in the main question it is said first or last, andI have been using last in every thing so sorry if i confused you and choose first row in this example.  and for the days' Day1='2-18-2019' Day2=`2-19-2019`, Day3='2-20-2019' and Day4=`2-21-2019`. That's why I have the 21 in the output because it is more than 3 days difference. Hope it clear

Comment: @SMO - `because it is more than 3 days difference` - it means each other? or with last? or with first?

Comment: the difference from the first mention

Comment: `That's why I have the 21 in the output because it is more than 3 days difference.` - so it means

Comment: if for `021, 23, Emirates` is input `2-18-2019,2-19-2019,2-20-2019, 2-21-2019,2-22-2019,2-23-2019` then output is `2-18-2019,2-21-2019,2-22-2019,2-23-2019` ?

Comment: the difference between '2-18-2019` and `2-21-2019` is more than 3 days that why we kept both

Comment: @SMO - ok, so if difference with first per groups is less like 3 days need only first value, if difference is more like 3 days need first value and then all days greater like difference 3 days?

Comment: No for `021, 23, Emirates` the output should be the first of every 3 days so `2-18-2019,2-21-2019`

Comment: @SMO - Ok, so if input `2-18-2019,2-19-2019,2-20-2019, 2-22-2019,2-23-2019` then get `2-18-2019,2-22-2019` ? because missing `2-21-2019`

Comment: yes that is what I exactly want for every group

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your effort and patience.

Comment: @SMO - one thinf, is possible per group duplicated dates? Like `2-18-2019,2-18-2019,2-20-2019, 2-22-2019,2-23-2019` - 2times `2-18-2019` ? then output is `2-18-2019,2-18-2019,2-22-2019` ?

Comment: No city code can appear only once every day

Comment: @SMO - And difference betwen days per groups is always 1 day? Or possible 2 days, or more days? Like `2-18-2019,2-19-2019,2-20-2019, 2-22-2019,2-23-2019`, between `2-20-2019, 2-22-2019` is difference 2 days

Comment: the difference can be more than one day. so city code can appear every day , every other day or even once a year

Comment: @SMO - not sure if test all usecases, please chec edited answer.

Comment: this one works. However the previous one that contains `def f(x):
     return (x.diff().dt.days.fillna(0).cumsum() // 3).duplicated()` worked also. and it made more sense to me. I'm really thankful for your time and effort.